# Slider de imagenes en fragmento

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

espero esten bien, tengo el siguiente error al tratar de llamar un adapter desde un fragmento

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el fragment que hace el llamado al adapter

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando creo el fragment como blank fragment no genera el error pero al hacerlo desde un botton navigation tab, ya me genera el error, espero me puedan ayudar, muchas gracias.
Soy novato en la programacion android.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: por favor, trata de subir codigo cuando hagas una pregunta, los screenshot no sirven de mucho si uno quiere testear lo que estas haciendo

Comment: alli dice que tienes un error en la linea 21 del xml del main activity

Comment: Gracias francisco lo tendre presente para las proximas preguntas

Comment: Puedes intentar llamar a `viewpager.adapter = adapter` de tu Fragment `HomeFragment` en el método `onViewCreated()`. Me parece que esa linea puede estar causando el error. Lo que pasa es que, quieres setear el adapter al viewpager, pero no se ha creado todavía. Para agregar adapter o valores a tus componentes se recomienda hacer en el método `onViewCreated()` que es donde todo el layout que tienes asociado a ese fragment ya se dibujó. Espero te ayude :)